# Fetch Single Document from Firestore

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I switched my database data from the Real-time Database to Firestore because I need more defined querying when it comes to my apps that I'm building. However, I'm needing a little bit of help because I'm trying to assign the values to the currentCustomer variable, but instead of putting `snapshot.child()...`, what do I need to do with document? Thank you!

**My Firestore Document**

[image]

**MyUtil.kt**

```
var currentCustomer: Customer? = null

        fun fetchCurrentCustomer() {

            val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid
            val ref = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("/$REF_CUSTOMERS/$uid")

            ref.get().addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                if (document != null) {
                    currentCustomer = Customer(
                        document.documents.,
                        snapshot.child("fullname").getValue(String::class.java)!!,
                        snapshot.child("username").getValue(String::class.java)!!,
                        snapshot.child("email").getValue(String::class.java)!!,
                        "",
                        snapshot.child("profileImageUrl").getValue(String::class.java)!!
                    )
                }
            }

         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this to fetch a single document from firestore collection**

```
val reference = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                            .collection("REF_CUSTOMERS")
                            .document($uid)
    
     reference.get().addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                    if (document != null) {
                           currentCustomer = document.toObject(Customer::class.java
                    }
                }
```